# How to make a POST request using the Collectd curl plugin?

Tags: curl, collectd

How do I make a post request using the curl plugin? I see no option where I can specify the post data, or the type of request.

Is it even possible with the plugin, or is there an alternative plugin I can use?

Answer (score 1):

While libcurl certainly supports the POST method ([example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html)), it appears that the specific functionality isn't exposed in the current version of the [collectd plugin](http://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_curl).

Your best shot is probably going to be to setup a server/service/page that can "proxy" the POST request for you through a GET request, and return the results.